Creating a hero video background with text using vuetify and nuxt
I am trying to do a hero video background using vuetify with an overlay and white text centered. I have a navigation bar I am trying to account for height to get as much video on the screen as possible and then also get the text good. My issue is the text will not show and also the video has a black bar up top which makes me think there is some dimensional issue. I am not sure of the best approach to do a video background with vuetify but overal I am trying to achieve this example:
https://guidefp.com
My layout is as follows:
    <template>
    <v-app>
        <v-layout>
            <v-app-bar class="px-md-4" color="grey-lighten-4" height="40" flat>
                <template #prepend>
                    <v-btn icon="mdi-facebook" variant="plain"/>
                    <v-btn icon="mdi-instagram" variant="plain"/>
                </template>
                <template v-if="$vuetify.display.mdAndUp" #append>
                    <v-btn class="ms-1 mx-5" color="primary" variant="plain" prepend-icon="mdi-account" rounded>Login</v-btn>
                    <v-btn class="ms-1" color="primary" variant="plain" prepend-icon="mdi-upload" rounded>File Upload</v-btn>
                </template>
            </v-app-bar>
            <v-app-bar :elevation="5" class="px-md-4" color="surface" height="100" flat>
                <template #prepend>
                        <v-app-bar-nav-icon
                        v-if="$vuetify.display.smAndDown"
                        @click="drawer = !drawer"
                        />
                </template>

                <v-spacer v-if="$vuetify.display.smAndDown"/>
                
                <v-img

                    class="me-sm-8"
                    max-width="240"

                    src="/img/logo-header.png"
                />

                <v-spacer />

                <template v-if="$vuetify.display.mdAndUp">
                    <v-btn
                    v-for="(item, i) in items"
                    :key="i"
                    :active="i === 0"
                    color="primary"
                    class="me-2 text-none"
                    v-bind="item"
                    size="large"
                    rounded
                    />
                </template>
            </v-app-bar>

            <v-main>
                <slot />
                <v-footer>
                </v-footer>
            </v-main>
        </v-layout>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </v-app>
</template>
<script setup>
  import { shallowRef } from 'vue'
  
  const drawer = shallowRef(false)

  const items = [
    {
      text: 'Home',
    },
    {
      text: 'About',
    },
    {
      text: 'Services',
    },
    {
      text: 'Resources',
    },
    {
      text: 'Blog',
    },
    {
      text: 'Contact',
    }
  ]
</script>


And my page implementing the full screen hero section is here:

    <template>
  <v-row>
    <v-card class="hero-video-container">
      <v-overlay
      v-model="overlay"
      :opacity="0.5"
      contained
      absolute
      persistent/>
      <video src="/video/hero-video.mp4" autoplay loop playsinline muted></video>
      <h1 class="text-h1 ">This is a test</h1>
    </v-card>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <v-card>
      this is a test
    </v-card>
  </v-row>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
  import {ref} from 'vue'
  
  definePageMeta({
    layout: "default",
  });

  const overlay = ref<boolean>(true)
  
</script>
<style>
.hero-video-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 120px);
}
.hero-video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
}
</style>

